# My Tomcat v9.0 server can not run a servlet listener clas despite correct xml file

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat9, servlet-listeners

Tomcat server could not find the servlet class. Even I tried only with a servlet class. Still, the server could not find the servlet class, giving the same error message. I am very new to web application.

[image: This the web.xml file]
[image: This is error message]
This is my servlet file.[image: servlet]

This is my listener file.[image: listener]

This is my expected output. If I put manually the link: http://localhost:8081/listener_Demo/TestServlet, I get it on console (look at console).[image: expected output]

Comment: Try accessing your servlet with this url `http://localhost:8081/listener_Demo/TestServlet`

Comment: @W-S, I have already tried it. It works. However, I could not find what is wrong. Why server can not find it on its own.

Comment: What do you mean by "why server cannot find it on its own"?

Comment: I do not know about the context path of an application. however, its the name of a dynamic web project. If you look at the left side, you will notice.

Comment: @ W-H, "why server cannot find it on its own" means why server get it from web.xml file. when I specifically put the link: http://localhost:8081/listener_Demo/TestServer, then only it works. otherwise server return the error page.

Comment: It because the server try to load one of your welcome file but cannot find it. Adding an index.html or index.jsp will do.

Answer (score 1):

Update `welcome-file-list` and add your custom jsp to open directly.

for example :

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>display.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now, you can use http://localhost:8081/listener_Demo/ to open directly your page.

Note you have to keep the .jsp in the root WEB-INF folder for accessing.

Comment: Removing it does not solve the problem.  Moreover, I do not have any custom .jsp file to add. I have just two file, one servlet and one listener. If you look at left corner, you notice it.

Comment: @NAZMULHUSSAIN I have updated my answer. You have not to remove it. You need to update it.

Comment: B I do not have any jsp file.

Comment: @NAZMULHUSSAIN what are trying to do ? Can you specify.

Comment: @NAZMULHUSSAIN what it should do when you access that url ?

Comment: look at the last three screenshots. I have updated the question.